# Trouble using if-statement and String.replace

Tags: java, str-replace

I have the following snippet for a hangman game I'm developing in Eclipse:

```
String secret = "apple";
String str = "-----"    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (letter == secret.charAt(i)){
        str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), letter);
    }   
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Unfortunately, this is printing out

```
aaaaa
```

instead of

```
a----
```

How would I get this working?

Comment: what is `letter` in this case? and anyway you can't use `==` to check `String` in java

Comment: No, this isn't compiling.

Comment: `String#replace(char, char)` replaces all occurrences of first char with the second, not just at a specified (you have not specified, because you cannot) position.

Comment: this just a small part in the whole code and letter is a char that the user enters and im checking chars not string

Comment: I wrote it fast here its System.out.print and i realize the fault in this thanks for the help

Comment: I used the char[] it was very helpful thank you @dktazel .

Answer (score 5):

The [JavaDoc of String#replace(char, char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) states that it will replace *all* occurrences not just the first.

Since you want to make a hangman game, you need to only replace the positions where `letter` appears in `secret`

It might be better to manually replace the characters in a String using a `StringBuilder` or a `char[]`

```
char[] secret="apple".toCharArray();
char[] str= new char[secret.length];
Arrays.fill(str, '-');

for (int i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
    if (letter ==secret[i]){
       str[i] = letter;
    }   
}

System.out.println(new String(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want really set only a character in a String, you could do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sbStr = new StringBuilder(str);
sbStr.setCharAt(4, 'x');
```

This is your code refactored:

```
String secret = "apple";
String str = "-----"    
StringBuilder sbStr = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (letter == secret.charAt(i)){
      sbStr.setCharAt(i, letter);
   }   
}
System.out.println(sbStr.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(str.charAt(i), letter);` will not work because it does not replace a single character, but all charachters in the String matching `str.charAt(i)`, what you could do is use StringBuilders to change the character at a given index, like this:

```
String secret = "apple";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("-----");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (letter == secret.charAt(i)){
        str.setCharAt(i, letter);
    }   
}
System.out.println(str.toString()); // Or simply: System.out.println(str);
```

If you don't want to use StringBuilder, something like this will also work:

```
String secret = "apple";
String str = "-----";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (letter == secret.charAt(i)){
        str = str.substring(0, i) + secret.charAt(i) + str.substring(i);
    }   
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Although I advice a StringBuilder in this case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use String builder for both **secret** and **str**, and mark guess character in secret too, because your solution may fails for repeating characters

```
        char letter = 'a';
        StringBuilder secret = new StringBuilder("apple");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("-----");


        int index = secret.indexOf(String.valueOf(letter));
        if(index != -1)
        {
            secret.setCharAt(index, '-');
            str.setCharAt(index, letter);
        }

        System.out.println(secret);
        System.out.println(str);
```

Hopes that Helps